# Updating XML file on server

Tags: javascript, tomcat, filewriter

I have an Eclipse project being run locally from my machine through Tomcat. The project is a web application with patients, HCPs, and administrators able to log in to do various tasks. One of these tasks is to run a group report on patients based on certain search criteria. After a group report is run, there should be an option to view the group report as in XML format.

The way that I have structured my project is I have created a groupReport.xml file locally. Once this file was created, I committed it so that when I run the project on a Tomcat server, I can manually point my browser to the website address of where the XML file is stored on my server (localhost:8080/project/groupReport.xml for example).

Each time that a group report is run, I have a java class that rewrites the groupReport.xml to reflect the new changes. This java class uses a FileWriter that writes it to the local path on my hard drive. The problem with this is that navigating to localhost:8080/project/groupReport.xml will only display the XML information for the group report that was first committed before the server was started. It does not reflect any changes to the XML that has been rewritten locally.

I have tried to use relative pathnames to have FileWriter write to the XML file being stored on the server side, but could not achieve the results I was looking for. Is there any way for the XML on my server (localhost:8080/project/groupReport.xml) to be rewritten any time the locally stored XML file is rewritten?

I do not know any PHP or Ajax, so if there's a similar solution using just Java and Javascript, that would be preferable.

Comment: Using the local filesystem in Tomcat is fraught with peril.  The Servlet spec makes no assumptions about the existence of a local filesystem, and you may or may not be able to access it except for temporary storage.  If you need to persist your report, you should write it to the database.

Comment: Well the XML file is being rewritten using elements from the database. I'm not quite sure how to rewrite an XML file and have it instantly reflected server side, since the project is being run locally from my machine through a Tomcat server. Can you explain what you mean by writing the XML file to the database?

Comment: Assuming this is a web app that can be accessed remotely, what do you expect to happen to the XML when the remote user saves the XML.  It will be on the server, not where the user is located, and they will not have access to it.

Comment: If I store the XML file on the server, then the user will be able to access it through the functionality of the website. However, my main problem at the moment is I have not been able to manipulate FileWriter in such a way that it rewrites the groupReport.xml that is server side. Instead, the only way that I have managed to have it work is that it rewrites the locally stored groupReport.xml, which as you have noted, would not be accessible to the user. This brings me back to the original question of how to rewrite the XML that is stored on the server side.

Comment: What happens if two different users attempt to write the file at the same time?  This model leads down a path where you have to set up locks to prevent race conditions and is just generally a bad idea.

Comment: Each groupReport.xml will have their filename suffixed with the ID of the HCP that is currently logged in. Since the system ensures that only one instance of each HCP can be logged in at once, it safeguards against writes to the same file at the same time. I really don't know how else I would generate an XML file upon running a group report without storing it on the server and rewriting it since PHP is beyond the scope of this course.